# What is causing the php error in my simplemodal contact form? :)

Tags: php, jquery, simplemodal

Wamp returns the following PHP error when I press 'send' in my simplemodal wordpress plugin contact form (version 1.2.6)

The wordpress version is 3.1....

I haven't made any changes to the installation.... Any ideas? I'm building the website for a local charity

->

```
( ! ) Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-settings.php on line 219
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0014  418128  {main}( )   ..\smcf_data.php:0
2   0.0020  432192  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-config.php' )   ..\smcf_data.php:3

( ! ) Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-settings.php on line 234
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0014  418128  {main}( )   ..\smcf_data.php:0
2   0.0020  432192  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-config.php' )   ..\smcf_data.php:3
```

(it carries on like this for a while!)

UPDATE---------------------------------------------------------

Thankyou for all your input.....So - my version of PHP seemed to be to blame. I changed to 5.2, from 5.35, and now 'send' returns no PHP error. The new error (of course!) is returned within the form, rather than as a server error as such, and reads -"Unfortunately, a server issue prevented delivery of your message." Do I need to configure wamp for use with the mail function? I'm running 127- localhost :)

Comment: PHP compatibility issue? Which version of PHP do you use? Try to download and run older version of PHP (if you use 5.3, try 5.2)

Comment: Please mention what version of PHP is being used by your WAMP installation. Also what version of WordPress does your plugin "SimpleModal WordPress Plugin" support?

Comment: Officially, 3.0.5 is the latest version of WP supported by the plugin ... not to say that's the issue, just the official line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first error was with WordPress and the version of PHP you were running.

The second error is due to the fact that you probably do not have SMTP configured. You need to configure PHP (php.ini) to use either a local or remote SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecation errors are just a notification, that using this feature is discouraged, because it won't be supported in the future. This can often happen when upgradig to newer versions. It actually doesn't mean that the code doesn't work, basically you can turn off this kind of error and ignore it or fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

These warnings come from assignments like `$foo =& new Classname();`. Since PHP 5.3 the usage of `=&` is deprecated. Nevertheless the code works so you could hide the warnings (error_reporting).
However I recommend to upgrade PHP.

Comment: PHP 5.3 doesn't deprecate the use of =&, it deprecates the usage of references created against a "new" object.  There's an important difference.  =& is still valid if used properly.